# Best practices for saving NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: ios, core-data

What is the best practice for saving `NSManagedObjectContext` in terms of frequency? Is it sufficient to do save only when the app is switching to the background or is about to terminate? Is it correct to assume that the normal semantics of working with managed objects is not affected by how often they are saved (from memory to SQLite).

(P.S. The editor indicates that the question "appears subjective and is likely to be closed" but the site contains other questions about core data best practices so I hope it's okay.)

Comment: Honestly, when I've worked with it and in an app I'm working on with near 1 million downloads, it has been saved immediately after the object has been finished with manipulation. Is there a reason that you're being cautious with saving the context? Are you dumping a lot of information at once? Or are you trying to avoid a lot of `[context save:&error]` calls?

Comment: @LyricalPanda It's the second (the many calls).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save it at key points in your app. For example if you have a screen where you want to modify an `NSManagedObject`, and you need to have a `cancelChangesButton` as well, you would want your `NSManagedObjectContext` to be saved at the moment you are entering this screen, so you can call `undo` on it and discard all the changes you've made on this screen.

Basically you should save when you are done working with an `NSManagedObject` if you are not doing some kind of processing in a cycle (`for`, `while` ...). If you do however, you should save after you exited the cycle, do not call save in every turn, otherwise it might slow your app.

Answer (score 0):

I've meanwhile noticed that saving is also convenient/helpful when deleting a managed object that is a member of a to-many inverse relationship. The object will be removed from the set that represents the relationship only when saving its managed object context.

Until then, the set still contains the deleted object (if marked as for deletion) so the set's `count` yields unexpected results (because it still includes deleted objects), and indices into the relationship (if it is an ordered one) are also off by corresponding amounts.

Overall, in such situations it seems much simpler to call `save:` than to perform special count and index calculations at various points.